# Accessing the value of a child component redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a form created using `redux-form` and have a requirement for display and filtering based on selections within the **child objects** of the form (being mapped using a `FieldArray`). The form data json structure is something like:

```
{ 
  name: "my form",
  selection: "1"
  date: "02/02/2020",
  children: 
      [{  
        childName: "child2",
        childSelection: "1",
        grandchildren: [{
                grandchild: "3"
              }]   
       },
       {
         childName: "child2",
         childSelection: "1",        
         grandchildren: [{
                grandchild: "2"
              }]   
       }
      ]
}
```

On the actual form I have a dropdown list for the field `selection`, `childSelection` and `grandchild`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {    
    const selector = formValueSelector(FORM_NAME); 
    const selection= selector(state, "selection")
    ...
```

I want to be able to filter the grandchildren dropdown whenever childSelection changes, amongst other UI requirements.

I understand that `redux-form` fires an `onChange` event, and I have written a selector like the above to capture the change of `selection` for the top level which works well, but when it comes to the child/grandchild - how do I know which item has changed to effect the filter (ie pass the child selection into the selector for the dropdown that drives the grandchildren list?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri how is this a duplicate? This is child data within the same form (ie within a `FieldArray` component mapping)

Comment: Your reduxForm has a state associated with it in store, you can access that state in any other component with the help of the question link that I added using Redux form name and the fieldName. Let me know if thats what you want. However that is what I understand from your question

Comment: I already showed in my code example that I know how to do that. What I want to understand is how to identify a child property that has been  changed in the form. The answer you linked to does not explain this